# Monitoring _current_ bandwidth used by Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, bandwidth, graph

Afternoon gents,

I'm trying to monitor and graph the *currently* used bandwidth by Apache, I've been trying to use mod_status with /server-status and just parsing this specific row:

```
16.1 requests/sec - 34.4 kB/second - 2193 B/request
```

But unfortunately that's an average value, which means that over time it will basically grind to a halt. What I'd like to do is to monitor the bandwidth usage over, lets say for simplicity's sake, 1 second. Any clues on how to do this?

Best Regards
Lpe

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just using standard network monitoring tools to graph ports 80 and 443?

Comment: To be completely honest, which I rarely am, I didn't even think of that, must think outside the box :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Ladadadada said in the comments: you can use the standard network metrics on the relevant ports.

You can also use server-status and look at "Total kBytes":

```
$ curl http://localhost/server-status?auto
Total Accesses: 4506
Total kBytes: 19993
CPULoad: .319462
Uptime: 62383
ReqPerSec: .0722312
BytesPerSec: 328.18
BytesPerReq: 4543.46
BusyWorkers: 1
IdleWorkers: 7
Scoreboard: ___W____............
```

And then do math (note the Uptime field, also, if you don't trust the timer in your script).  Use the "?auto" to give machine-parseable output.

Comment: Hm, yeah, that would need some scripting but I guess that's alright, thank you.

Comment: Any thoughts if I'd like to monitor it per virtual host as well?
I guess that would require parsing specific access logs.

Comment: Might be other tools available: http://www.debian-administration.org/users/shoof/weblog/1

Comment: Also this: http://serverfault.com/questions/181706/monitoring-of-the-virtual-host-apache-bandwidth-and-visitors-via-nagios

Answer (score 1):

Since a single second goes by fairly quickly, I presume you'd like a MAX HOLD function with that :)

Check out [**apachetop**](http://freecode.com/projects/apachetop).

Comment: Yeah you got a point, and hopefully you get mine as well. :-)
I actually tried apachetop, but as far as I understood I can't make it just prints the values, it seems to be interactive-only which is not really ideal for graphing specific values, I'd gladly be proven wrong though.